# Better way to update value in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In sessionStroage,

> key : qq
>
> value : [{"javascript":800},{"python":600},{"html":300}]

I will make some change in it, for examle, just change `python` to 1000 (I don't know its order in array)

Simulation code

```
// set storage
sessionStorage.setItem('qq', JSON.stringify([{'javascript': 800}, {'python': 600}, {'html': 300}]));

// get from storage
var ss =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('qq'));
```

This is what I try

```
// for-loop to update value to 'python'
for (var i in ss) {
    if (Object.keys(ss[i])[0] === 'python'){
        ss[i][Object.keys(ss[i])[0]] = 1000;
    }
}
```

It works, but it is quite a little bit complicated and not intuitive, is there a better way to do that?

any opinion is ok, thanks inadvanced.

Comment: What about the way you'd normally use a key/value store? As in, the one demonstrated in the MDN page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I don't know why my question get downvote :-(   There are many UI(drowdown list) in my web, I need to log what the user change, so I save them into storage, then just submit to update value in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve so by using simple `ForEach` method.The **forEach()** method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```js
var ss = [{'javascript': 800}, {'python': 600}, {'html': 300}]
console.log("Before  "+JSON.stringify(ss))
ss.forEach(function(element) {
if(Object.keys(element) == 'python'){
     element['python'] = 1000;
   }
});
console.log("After "+JSON.stringify(ss))
```

Comment: This won't work if `element` has keys other than `python`. It may be better to use `element.hasOwnProperty('python');`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
arr.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('python')).python = 1000;
```

```js
var arr = [{'javascript': 800}, {'python': 600}, {'html': 300}];
arr.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('python')).python = 1000;
console.log(arr);
```

This will update the value in the `arr` itself which can then be converted to a string and stored into sessionStorage.

Comment: What if the object doesn't exist in the array? Wouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't work if `python` is set to a falsey value, such as 0, or empty string

Comment: @user184994 True. `hasOwnProperty` will help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If your app permits, you could store the value as an `object` instead of an `Array`, then just lookup the item by key:

key: qq
value: { "javascript": 800, "python": 600, "html": 300 }

After pulling it out of storage and parsing it would then be:

```
var ss = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('qq'));

ss.python = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention it clearly, for python, javascript... is the key in my example. But I also have author, published date to combine the key